# Storing Multiple Insert IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, common-table-expression

After scouring the site (and others...), I cannot find an example of an insert command allowing me to store the "RETURNING" values to a table, CTE, etc. This is what I'd like to do:

```
WITH insert_rows AS (
  INSERT INTO employers (column1, column2, insert_date)
  SELECT distinct tc.column1, 'any text', now()
  FROM _tmp_employer_updates tc
  LEFT JOIN employers e ON e.column1 = tc.column1
  WHERE e.column1 IS NULL   -- Only insert non-existing employer names
  RETURNING employer.row_uuid, employer.column1, employer.column2;
  )
SELECT * FROM insert_rows; -- table of returning values
```

Is there anyway to get an insert command to store it's "returning" values to a table using a CTE? When I try the example above I get:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 1: ... _tmp_inserted_employers AS WITH insert_rows AS ( INSERT INT...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what version are you using? I think this feature became available in 9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` after `returning ...`, remove alias `employer` before columns in `returning` (or change it to `employers`). Otherwise your query looks good.

Here's an example on **[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/49825/1)**.

Comment: Ahh...Thanks! The version is the issue for me. Ironically I'm running 9.0 on my local dev box and my dev server is running 9.1.6. As you may have guessed, I'm running it on my local dev box and it does not work. However if I run it on my dev server, it works fine. Thanks again! :-)